# creating Datatable JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I require some help in creating a datatable. In the datatable, the second column should be divided into  4 columns. Can you please let me know how to achieve the same using JSF.  Thanks in Advance. 
[image: example of table header]

Comment: use another h:dataTable with four columns inside second h:column tag

Comment: if you are using primefaces, p:columnGroup has to be used http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableGrouping.jsf

Comment: @rags it would be better if you post an answer. By the way, I bet that you haven't tried the proposed solution in your first comment, if you test it you'll see that it won't work.

Comment: @vr3w3c9 for future questions, post what have you tried instead of asking how to do your work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PrimeFaces you can use [`p:columnGroup`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableGrouping.jsf):

```
<p:dataTable>
    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="TType"/>
            <p:column colspan="4" headerText="Capacity"/>
            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Availability"/>
        </p:row>
        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="Litre"/>
            <p:column headerText="Weight"/>
            <p:column headerText="Vol"/>
            <p:column headerText="Value"/>
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>
    <p:column>
        Ttype
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        Litre
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        Weight
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        Vol
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        Value
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        Availability
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```